# invalid syntax for sep using print() python 3

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I am new to Python. So I am stuck with this issue which I think shouldn't happen if I use Python 3.

I have a list a with (1,2,3,4,5,6). I want to print it out in 123456 form (without any space). So I wrote this code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
print(a, sep="")
```

But I always get this error:

```
        print(a, sep="") 
                    ^ 
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Are you *sure* you're running a Python 3 interpreter? That's exactly the error I'd expect from Python 2 (where the parentheses would be surrounding a tuple, rather than being part of a function call).

Comment: I am. I'm running a software called Canopy and I have using the print function like python 3. This is the only place where it's giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't work out why that code isn't running, unless it is that you are running a python 2 interpretor (as @blckknght suggests). However, when I want to do this, I use the following code, which works every time:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in lst: print(i, end="")
print()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Canopy is [python2 based distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/). Quoting official docs (**emphasis mine**):

> An Enthought Canopy subscription provides **Python 2.7.11**, easy
>   installation and updates of over 400 pre-built and tested scientific
>   and analytic Python packages such as NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, Matplotlib,
>   and IPython, PLUS an integrated analysis environment, graphical
>   debugger, data import tool, and online Python Essentials and Python
>   Development Tools training courses. Academic users may request a free
>   Canopy Academic license.

If you've been using print function in that environment, it had to be prepended with `__future__` import

```
from __future__ import print_function
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
print(a, sep="")
```

Code above works fine in Python 2.7. Without `__future__` import, it yields exact exception as quoted by you.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I tried you solution but it didn't give me desired output. I got the following:
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

So tried something on my own:
         from __future__ import print_function
         x = int(input())
         for i in range(1,x+1):
                         print(i, sep='', end='')
I got the following output for input 6:
         123456
So I really don't why it doesn't give me output for the list

Comment: Try `print(*a, sep="")` if you want to print the items from the list, without the brackets or commas. The other way to do it in Python 2 (without the `print` function) is `print "".join(str(x) for x in a)`.